# Change animation while pushing view controller in Objectiove c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, push, transition

While pushing `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController` I want to get transition like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FcvfrV-FhY

I am using this code to push view controller :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

In video please note that there is no gray effect and secondViewController does not   shows over firstViewController during transition, I want similar transition.

Comment: I think in video they are showing two UIViews in a scroll view. I think its just scrolling animation.

Comment: But we need scroll only in one direction that is left to right but not from right to left.
I think there should be a way to customize push transition to get similar behavior.